# Mac M1 not able to map PHP 8.0.3 as a CLI Interpreter within PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, apple-m1

So I just installed XAMPP and PhpStorm on my Macbook Pro M1 so that I could start working with PHP. However, it seems that the M1 can't recognize the interpreter in path `/Applications/XAMPP/bin/php` . I got this path after running `which php`.

I'm running PHP 8.0.3.

[image]

So when I run the file in the browser I get `404 Not found` OR `502 Bad Gateway`.

How do I correctly configure PHP interpreter in PhpStorm for the M1? Is there another option?

[image: Not Found error]

Comment: Based on the URL in the browser (on your 2nd screenshot) you are using PhpStorm's built-in simple web server and not Apache from your XAMPP. Please define a Deployment entry (In-Place type is fine so no file copying), provide the URL that you wish to use there (that will utilize XAMPP) and mark the entry as Default for the project. This way PhpStorm will be using THAT URL when you use "Open in Browser" or alike instead of default built-in web server (which is limited in what it can do and can have issues in some setups).

Comment: P.S. From what I see the PHP Interpreter is actually got recognized correctly. BTW: it is used for executing PHP code in CLI environment, to run your local tools (like PHPUnit, Composer etc) and by built-in simple web server. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/installing-an-amp-package.html#integrating-xampp

Comment: @LazyOne When you say "the url that utilizes XAMPP", what do you mean? Which URL should I put?

Comment: PhpStorm's built-in simple web server (the one you are using based on URL from your screenshot) is quite basic and can have issues. That's why I ALSWAYS suggest to use proper web server (Apache from XAMPP/MAMP of whatever you may have got there, IIS on Windows, nginx etc). The idea here: configure your Apche from XAMPP to serve those pages. Then you may use such URL in PhpStorm deployment settings (so it uses that URL as a base when you use "Open in Browser" or alike action from inside the IDE).